# Ignoring 2 commits after a 'git reset --hard' command

Tags: git, git-bash

I'm a beginner with Git. So here's the scenario, In an empty text file, I added `One` String and performed the following command:

```
git init
git add sample.txt
git commit -m "Added One"
git push origin master
```

Next, I added `Two` on the next line and performed the following command:

```
git add sample.txt
git commit -m "Added Two"
git push origin master
```

And ended up until `Three` making it contain:

```
One
Two
Three
```

Then I performed `git reset --hard 'value of the first commit here'` to bring back the file which contains `One` and added `Four` making it:

```
One
Four
```

So when I performed a commit and push, the following error showed:

```
Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart.
```

How can I push my commit rejecting the other 2 commits so that the final text file will contain:

```
One
Four
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to "force push", to forcibly replace the branch on origin with your local branch:

```
git push -f
```

Comment: Is there any consequences in using this command?

Comment: You will obviously lose the commits you overwrite, and anybody sharing your repository will have to reset their branch to the same state as yours.

Comment: Is there any command that will do this as well as retained the commits in log. I performed `git log` but the 2 commits where deleted in logs.

Comment: @ajdeguzman No, that makes no sense. You cannot both retain the commits in your branch and *not* retain the commits in your branch. If you want to keep a reference to those commits, check out a new branch.